# How to add a primary key in a Rails migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

How can I add a unique, auto-incrementing primary key (`IdCustomer`) in Rails? And what about if I have more than one key?

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.integer :IdCustomer
      t.string :Login
      t.string :Password
      t.string :Email
      t.string :Skype
      t.integer :ICQ
      t.string :Firstname
      t.string :Lastname
      t.string :Country
      t.string :State
      t.string :City
      t.string :Street
      t.string :Building
      t.integer :Room
      t.string :AddressNote
      t.date :DateOfReg
      t.integer :CustGroup
      t.float :TotalBuy

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Help me with this, please, get it on my code. Becouse now i get

> rake aborted! An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto
>   column and it must be defined as a key: CREATE TABLE `credit_cards`
>   (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `IdCustomer`
>   int(11), `IdCard` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
>   `Number` varchar(255), `NameOfCard` int(11), `ExpiryDate` date,
>   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL)
>   ENGINE=InnoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set more than 1 column `auto_increment`. Delete `auto_increment PRIMARY KEY` after `IdCard int(11) DEFAULT NULL` and put `UNIQUE` instead if you want to make that column unique

Comment: how do this in migration I asked!